# DNS CNAME infinite recursion

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

DNS can handle recursions in CNAME fields. But I was just wondering what would happen if I do something like this, when configuring the DNS for the example.com domain:

```
a   IN      CNAME  b.example.com
b   IN      CNAME  a.example.com
```

Will this really cause an infinite recursion?

Comment: Try it and let us know.

Comment: I'm actually waiting for the DNS server to be updated at this very moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is possible to create loops using `CNAME` records, this is a type of error that can be expected to occur and the spec has been clear all along that the resolver is supposed to detect this and abort.

> Of course, by the robustness principle, domain software should not
> fail when presented with CNAME chains or loops; CNAME chains should be
> followed and CNAME loops signalled as an error.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.6.2

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the client that you are using. A smart one will detect the loop, while a trivial client may keep doing recursive lookups hitting your computer's DNS cache.